# check if pair of values is in pair of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically, I have latitude and longitude (on a grid) in two different columns. I am getting fed two-element lists (could be numpy arrays) of a new coordinate set and I want to check if it is a duplicate before I add it.

For example, my data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,8, 'wolf', 'Predator', 10],
              [5,6,'cow', 'Prey', 10],
              [8, 2, 'rabbit', 'Prey', 10],
              [5, 3, 'rabbit', 'Prey', 10],
              [3, 2, 'cow', 'Prey', 10],
              [7, 5, 'rabbit', 'Prey', 10]],
              columns = ['lat', 'long', 'name', 'kingdom', 'energy'])

newcoords1 = [4,4]
newcoords2 = [7,5]
```

Is it possible to write one `if` statement to tell me whether there is already a row with that latitude and longitude. In pseudo code:

```
if newcoords1 in df['lat', 'long']:
    print('yes! ' + str(newcoords1))
```

(In the example, `newcoords1` should be `false` and `newcoords2` should be `true`.

Sidenote: `(newcoords1[0] in df['lat']) & (newcoords1[1] in df['long'])` doesn't work because that checks them independently, but I need to know if that combination appears in a single row.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [140]: df.query('@newcoords2[0] == lat and @newcoords2[1] == long')
Out[140]:
   lat  long    name kingdom  energy
5    7     5  rabbit    Prey      10

In [146]: df.query('@newcoords2[0] == lat and @newcoords2[1] == long').empty
Out[146]: False
```

the following line will return a number of found rows:

```
In [147]: df.query('@newcoords2[0] == lat and @newcoords2[1] == long').shape[0]
Out[147]: 1
```

or using NumPy approach:

```
In [103]: df[(df[['lat','long']].values == newcoords2).all(axis=1)]
Out[103]:
   lat  long    name kingdom  energy
5    7     5  rabbit    Prey      10
```

this will show whether at least one row has been found:

```
In [113]: (df[['lat','long']].values == newcoords2).all(axis=1).any()
Out[113]: True

In [114]: (df[['lat','long']].values == newcoords1).all(axis=1).any()
Out[114]: False
```

Explanation:

```
In [104]: df[['lat','long']].values == newcoords2
Out[104]:
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [105]: (df[['lat','long']].values == newcoords2).all(axis=1)
Out[105]: array([False, False, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I have a question that extends on this; in particular the numpy approach: `df[(df[['lat','long']].values == newcoords2).all(axis=1)]`. How would I apply this, but when newcoords is a DataFrame or array of value pairs, if I wanted to avoid a large python for loop?

Answer (score 4):

for people like me who came here by searching how to check if several pairs of values are in a pair of columns within a big dataframe, here an answer.

Let a list `newscoord = [newscoord1, newscoord2, ...]` and you want to extract the rows of `df` matching the elements of this list. Then for the example above:

```py
v = pd.Series( [ str(i) + str(j) for i,j in df[['lat', 'long']].values ] )
w = [ str(i) + str(j) for i,j in newscoord ]

df[ v.isin(w) ]
```

Which gives the same output as @MaxU, but it allows to extract several rows in once.

On my computer, for a `df` with 10,000 rows, it takes 0.04s to run.

Of course, if your elements are already strings, it is simpler to use `join` instead of concatenation.

Furthermore, if the order of elements in the pair does not matter, you have to sort first:

```py
v = pd.Series( [ str(i) + str(j) for i,j in np.sort( df[['lat','long']] ) ] )
w = [ str(i) + str(j) for i,j in np.sort( newscoord ) ]
```

To be noted that if `v` is not converted into a series and one uses `np.isin(v,w)`, or i `w` is converted into a series, it would require more run time when `newscoord` reaches thousands of elements.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it really helped me. rather than checking for a couple of values in your dataframe. you transformed that in one string . It's definitely easier to compare ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

```
x, y = newcoords1

>>> df[(df.lat == x) & (df.long == y)].empty
True  # Coordinates are not in the dataframe, so you can add it.

x, y = newcoords2

>>> df[(df.lat == x) & (df.long == y)].empty
False  # Coordinates already exist.
```

Comment: `((df.lat == x) & (df.long == y)).any()` saves a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check several pairs at once, you can put the DataFrame's columns and the values into MultiIndexes and use [Index.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html). I believe this is cleaner than concatenating them as strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,8, 'wolf', 'Predator', 10],
          [5,6,'cow', 'Prey', 10],
          [8, 2, 'rabbit', 'Prey', 10],
          [5, 3, 'rabbit', 'Prey', 10],
          [3, 2, 'cow', 'Prey', 10],
          [7, 5, 'rabbit', 'Prey', 10]],
          columns = ['lat', 'long', 'name', 'kingdom', 'energy'])

new_coords = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(4,4), (7,5)])
existing_coords = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[["lat", "long"]])
~new_coords.isin(existing_coords)
>>> array([ True, False])
```